# Sever-timing Trailer in Golang Server

Tags: http, go

I need to record something in the server-timing header after writing to request body. And I add a middleware in the golang server.

```golang
w.Header().Set("Trailer", "Server-Timing")
handler.ServeHTTP(...) 
// xxxx will collect information to transfer  to server-timing format
w.Header().Set("Server-Timing", xxx.String())
```

So, how did the chrome/firehox show the trailers? Will the explorer show the trailers in the Header or Timing?

Answer (score 1):

Firefox DevTools support the Server-Timing trailer headers.

Chrome DevTools used to support it too, but currently there's a [regression as of April 2022](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1280260.) (at least on macOS).

NOTE: I've just finished writing a Go middleware package for this. I'll open source it in the upcoming days and will let you know.